# tomcat can have only two concurrency

Tags: jsp, tomcat, concurrency

I installed apache-tomcat-6.0.37 and created a very simple web app. Then I created a jsp as following:

```
<%@   page   contentType="text/html;   charset=GB2312"   %> 

<%

    System.out.println("begin" + Thread.currentThread().getName());

    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() +":" +  session.getId());

    Thread.sleep(30000);

    System.out.println("end" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
%>
```

I opened multiple tabs on Firefox. Visited this jsp on each tab, but only two threads was spawned to execute the request.

My question is why tomcat only spawned two threads to handle requests? How can I improve the concurrency?

Answer (score 0):

To be very simple:
Tomcat uses threadpool to serve each request and threads are only created when there are no threads in the pool to serve the current request.

So if there are threads in the thread pool, tomcat won't create a new thread and will use it from the thread-pool. In your case it might have been that the thread which served your request in the first tab might have returned to the pool and hence new thread was not created.

You can increase the number of maximum threads that will be created by modifying the `maxThreads` attribute of `<Connector>`. Here is a [good link](http://tomcat-configure.blogspot.in/2009/01/tomcat-maxthreads-configuration.html) for more-info.

Also the number of threads always in the thread-pool is determined by `minSpareThreads` attribute of http connector and the default for Tomcat-7 is `10`.

To know more about `HTTP Connector` configuration, what better than the [official docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html).

Comment: Actually I send more than 2 requests to tomcat, but tomcat only handled two requests. The maxThreads was set to 250. So my question why tomcat can't handle more than 2 requests concurrently?

Comment: "but tomcat only handled two requests."   So what have happened with the other requests?

Answer (score 0):

Let's do some experiments
First, you can try the following code which I have modified.

```
long begin = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println("begin---" + Thread.currentThread().getName()+ "  "+begin);
System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() +":" +  session.getId());
Thread.sleep(30000);
long end = System.currentTimeMillis() - begin;
System.out.println("end----" + Thread.currentThread().getName()+"  "+end);
```

You will find tomcat delayed receiving the request.
So the performance is no concern of Tomcat.

Second, we change the url and added some parameter.
Visited this jsp add some different parameter (like `/?param1`, `/?param2`) on each tab, many threads were spawned to execute the request.

Answer:
Certain browsers will serialize requests to the same URL if accessed from different windows.

Solution? I know you'll see.

Comment: What do you mean by 'revice'?